# How can I return value(object) form filter method on Object.keys() instead of key?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

```js
const notes = {
  'jk2334|notes-md-23': {
    id: 'notes-md-23',
    text: 'First Note'
  },
  'jk2334|notes-xd-34': {
    id: 'notes-xd-34',
    text: 'Second Note'
   },
   'fd4345|notes-mf-54': {
    id: 'notes-mf-54',
    text: 'Third Note'
   }
}

const result = Object.keys(notes).filter(note => {
        if(note.startsWith('jk2334')) {
            console.log('from inner -', notes[note]);
            return notes[note];
        }
    })

console.log(result)
```

If I run this code it returns only key but not the value of the object. But if I console inside the condition it returns the value.

I want to return the array of value not key. What should I do now?

Comment: Are you trying to get the *first* matching value? All matching values?

Comment: `filter` returns only the elements of the array if the return value is truthy.

Comment: filter filters the array of keys here so you only get subset of keys. you can try Object.entries()

Comment: all matching values.

Comment: I can get value using reduce but how to get value using filter

Comment: I want the result like the consoled value from inside the if condition not only key(note)

Comment: like - result = [{
    id: 'notes-md-23',
    text: 'First Note'
  },{
    id: 'notes-xd-34',
    text: 'First Note'
  }]

Comment: @MdMuazAhmed Did you check the answers below?

Comment: yes... I got the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The callback to `Array#filter` is expected to return a boolean value. `true` if you want to keep the value and `false` if you don't. You cannot use it to convert input values to different output values. The code you have works accidentally because objects are truthy values.

To convert input to output values you can call `Array#map` after filtering to map the keys back to values:

```js
const notes = {
  'jk2334|notes-md-23': {
    id: 'notes-md-23',
    text: 'First Note'
  },
  'jk2334|notes-xd-34': {
    id: 'notes-xd-34',
    text: 'Second Note'
   },
   'fd4345|notes-mf-54': {
    id: 'notes-mf-54',
    text: 'Third Note'
   }
}

const result = Object.keys(notes)
  .filter(note =>  note.startsWith('jk2334'))
  .map(key => notes[key])

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score -1):

You could combine filtering and mapping with reducing the array.

```js
const
    notes = { 'jk2334|notes-md-23': { id: 'notes-md-23', text: 'First Note' }, 'jk2334|notes-xd-34': { id: 'notes-xd-34', text: 'Second Note' }, 'fd4345|notes-mf-54': { id: 'notes-mf-54', text: 'Third Note' } },
    result = Object
        .entries(notes)
        .reduce((r, [k, v]) => k.startsWith('jk2334') ? [...r, v] : r, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```